# Style Select And Multiple Select?

Tags: html, css, forms, select

How can I style both the `<select>` HTML tag, and the `<select multiple="multiple">` HTML tag while both of the tags reside under a `<form>` tag? Of course styling within CSS. If someone knows how to accomplish this, may someone give me an example?

Thank you!
Aaron

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you want to style? The question is not clear.

Comment: @Ronak - I edited the question, I didn't add code tags around the code lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use classes fairly easily:

```
.singleSelect {
  width: 200px;
}

.singleMultiple {
  width: 300px;
}

<form>
 <select class="singleSelect">
  <option>Test</option>
 </select>'
 <br/>
 <select class="singleMultiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Test 1</option>
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Test 3</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GyxL4/

A more advanced selector may be used on the `select[multiple]`, but beware, legacy browsers (**EDIT**: apparently only IE6) may not always support the attribute selector, and in the first example below, you're styling every `SELECT` element on the page (this is called an element selector):

```
select {
  width: 200px;
}

select[multiple] {
  width: 300px;
}
```

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Jared, thank you so much. I should of thought of that before, I looked way too much into it lol. Do you know of what CSS Attributes will work with the <select> HTML Tags?

Comment: Look at the first table here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6, below `%attrs;`, and below *Attributes defined elsewhere*.